# .NET Core console application, where is the connection string stored

Tags: asp.net-core, .net-core, entity-framework-core, console-application

Inside Visual Studio 2019 I have created a .NET Core console application. Then I use the below command to map existing database -

```
PM> Scaffold-DbContext "Server=.\MSSQL;Database=SchoolDB;Trusted_Connection=True;" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models
```

The above command mapped all the tables inside the `SchoolDB` database. But I have the following question -

1. inside my asp.net core web application, where is the connection string saved? So I can change it when I move my console application from test to the live environment.

Here is how my console application looks like after running the above command, where I can not find any configuration file to store the connection string -

[image]

Comment: Reference [Configuration in ASP.NET Core](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/aspnet/core/fundamentals/configuration)

Comment: You'll probably have to add it yourself.

Comment: @Nkosi but how is the application getting the data from? if i do not have  connection string?

Comment: The console app when run gets data?

Comment: Check the dbcontext code. It is most likely hard coded into the class's `OnConfiguring` method

Comment: @Nkosi yes you are correct the connection string is inside the `OnConfiguring` method.. but since the connection string is a configuration that will be changed when moving the application, so can i place it inside a `web.config`.... i am not sure but my .net core console application does not have a web.config ..

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The `Scaffold-DbContext` command should create a class `SchoolDBContext` in a file named `SchoolDBContext.cs` and it should be placed in the directory you specified with the `-OutputDir` parameter in the command. This class has a `OnConfiguring` method where the connection string is defined as -

```cs
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer("your_connection_string");
    }
}
```

If you want `SchoolDBContext` to be placed in a separate directory, you can use the `-ContextDir` parameter in the command to specify it, like -

```
Scaffold-DbContext "your_connection_string" Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore.SqlServer -OutputDir Models -ContextDir DbContext
```

**EDIT:**
If you want to put the connection string to a config file -

1. add a `.json` file (e.g. appconfig.json) at the root of your project and put the following content in it -

```json
{
  "ConnectionStrings": {
    "myDbConn": "your_connection_string"
  }
}
```

2. in the solution explorer, right click on the `appconfig.json` file and select `Properties`. Set the value of `Copy to Output Directory` to `Copy Always`.
3. install the `Microsoft.Extensions.Configuration.Json` package
4. modify the `OnConfiguring` method to -

```cs
protected override void OnConfiguring(DbContextOptionsBuilder optionsBuilder)
{
    var config = new ConfigurationBuilder()
        .AddJsonFile("appconfig.json", optional: false).Build();

    if (!optionsBuilder.IsConfigured)
    {
        optionsBuilder.UseSqlServer(config.GetConnectionString("myDbConn"));
    }
}
```

Comment: yes you are correct the connection string is inside the OnConfiguring method.. but since the connection string is a configuration that will be changed when moving the application, so can i place it inside a web.config.... i am not sure but my .net core console application does not have a web.config ..

Comment: @johnGu Please check the `EDIT`.

Comment: ok thanks for the reply.. your approach worked for me.. but the only issue is that if i regenerate the DB , then the modification inside the `OnConfiguring` method will be lost.. and i will need to re-modify the `OnConfiguring` method.. so is there a way to fix this?

Comment: @johnGu Re-running the command will re-generate the DbContext class and `OnConfiguring` method. I don't think you can avoid that.